# How to make object move in a triangle motion in Javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I've created a circle that I want to animate so that it moves in a triangle motion using if statements, and changing the y/x coordinates, but all I can make it do is go back and forth, so I was wondering if anyone could help?

the function where I'm changing the x/y parameters is called "triangle".

the full js code:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var w = 1000;
var h = 600;
var allCircles = [];



setUpCanvas();
createData(1);



 animationLoop();





function animationLoop(){
    clear();
    circlesDrawUpdate(allCircles);

    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}


function circlesDrawUpdate(a){
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        circle(a[i]);
        triangle(a[i]);
    }
}

function createData(num){
    for (var i=0; i<num; i++){
        allCircles.push({
            "x": w/2,
            "y": h/2,
            "dx": randn(100),
            "dy": 3,
            "r": 50,
            "c":200+rand(180),
            "a": 0.5,
        })
    }
}





function triangle(o){
    var i;
    o.x += o.dx;
    o.y += o.dy;
    if(o.y = h){
        o.dy *= +1;
    }

    if(o.x> w || o.x < 0){
        o.dx *=-1;
    
    }
}


function clear(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
}



function circle(o){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(o.x,o.y,o.r,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "hsla("+o.c+", 100%, 50%, "+o.a+")";
    ctx.fill();
}

function randn(r){
    var result = Math.random()*r - r/2;
    return result;
}

function randi(r){
    var result = Math.floor(Math.random()*r);
    return result;
}

function rand(r){
    var result = Math.random()*r;
    return result;
}

function setUpCanvas(){
    canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.style.border ="5px dashed purple";
}




console.log("Module 7 Exercise");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you meant by "triangle motion"?

```
function triangle(o) {
    o.x += o.dx;
    o.y += o.dy;
    if(o.y == h || o.y == 0){
        o.dy *= -1;
    }

    if(o.x >= w || o.x <= 0){
        o.dx *=-1;
    }
}
```

The reason why your circle kept going only back and forth is because first condition in your triangle function, where you assigned value ('=') instead of comparison ('=='). o.dy variable has been changed to h in every function call, therefore y value of your circle was always equal to canvas height.

Another problem is that you should multiply o.dy by -1 to change direction (same as you did in o.dx).

Last thing is checking both sides of your canvas (0 and h), not only the bottom one (h) (again, same as you did in o.dx)